# Spawning a Python Tkinter process through Rust's spawn does not give the stdout continuously

Tags: python, tkinter, rust

I'm starting an individual process from Rust like this:

```rust
let stdout = std::process::Command::new("python3")
    .arg(tool_path)
    .args(python_params)
    .stdout(std::process::Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .unwrap()
    .stdout
    .ok_or_else(|| "Could not capture standard output.")
    .unwrap();
```

I'm starting a Python process of my script and print it out like so:

```rust
let reader = std::io::BufReader::new(stdout);

reader
    .lines()
    .filter_map(|line| line.ok())
    .for_each(|line| println!("{}", line));
```

This will continuously print out all my prints inside my Python script. If my Python script looks like this:

```py
print("foo.pyyyyyyy")
while True:
    print("asdasd")
```

I will see first "foo.pyyyyyyy" printed, and then a continuous stream of "asdasd" prints in my terminal.

However, if my Python script consists of a Tkinter update loop like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome to LikeGeeks app")
window.mainloop()
print("foo.pyyyyyyy")
```

It does not print the "foo.pyyyyyyy" statement until after I terminate the external process.

Is there a way to circumvent this? I would really like to be able to pipe my Tkinter prints to my Rust app.

Comment: `window.mainloop()` does not return until all Tkinter windows are closed.  So the following `print("foo.pyyyyyyy")` line *didn't actually execute* until the program ended.

Comment: @jasonharper I failed to clarify, I tried it once before the main loop and once inside the loop as well but got similar issues

Comment: Ok, that might be a buffering issue.  If you print a *lot* of data (4K at least), does it start coming through?

Comment: It does! Putting a while true print loop both before and inside the tkinter loop eventually lets it print

Comment: There may be some way to set your IO channel to a line-buffered or unbuffered mode, so you get the data immediately - but I know nothing of Rust, so can't help you with that.

Comment: Try calling `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print()` statement.

Comment: @acw1668 That works, if I put that after a print statement it gets printed. If I try to print more afterwards without flushing it doesn't work though..

Comment: Try passing `-u` argument to the python command line.

Comment: Or try adding `-u` argument when calling python in Rust.

Comment: That solved it! Passing the `-u`flag made it possible to print without flushing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jmb and @acw1668 for the answer:

My issue had something to do with the I/O buffer when starting my python script. Adding the `-u` flag when calling my script solved the issues:
`python3 -u path_to_script parameters`

from the docs:

```
-u
Force the binary layer of the stdout and stderr streams
(which is available as their buffer attribute) to be unbuffered.
The text I/O layer will still be line-buffered if writing to the console,
or block-buffered if redirected to a non-interactive file.

See also PYTHONUNBUFFERED.
```